# shutil.copytree fails with FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: python, windows, filesystems

I have the following simple Python script on Windows:

```
import os.path
import shutil

src = os.path.join("..", "_build")
dst = "_build"
print("Copying {} to {}".format(src, dst))
if not os.path.exists(dst):
    shutil.copytree(src, dst)
    print("Copied {} to {}".format(src, dst))
else:
    print("{} already exists".format(dst))
```

Which when I run I get the following error:

```
>python copytreetest.py
Copying ..\_build to _build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copytreetest.py", line 9, in <module>
    shutil.copytree(src, dst)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 315, in copytree
    os.makedirs(dst)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: '_build'
```

Here is a screenshot to show that the destination "_build" does in fact not exist:

[image: windowsbug]

If I change the destination from "_build" to "_build2" then I don't get an error:

```
>python copytreetest.py
Copying ..\_build to _build2
Copied ..\_build to _build2
```

What on earth is going on here? Why is Windows in one instance (during the exists call) saying the destination does not exist, and in another (during the mkdir call) saying the destination DOES exist. Which Windows bug could I be encountering here? I'm running Windows Server 2016 version 1607.

**EDIT:** I found that the error was caused because I had a terminal open inside that _build directory. I guess somehow there is a conflict where you can delete a directory that a terminal has open, but cannot create another one with the same name (even though it appears to not exist). This is obviously confusing so I'll leave this question here in case anyone comes across the same problem.

Comment: A process has a handle for its working directory, but this should be open without delete sharing. An attempt to delete this directory should fail as a sharing violation. If not, it's a bug in the OS. Can you reproduce the problem?